# how to draw a looping rectangle in a for statement in java

Tags: java

i have been trying to make a program in java that makes a rectangle that gets bigger and bigger using a for loop. ive been getting stuck on this problem for like 2 hours and i really need help.

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
for( int i = 20; i <= 26; i++ ) {
            g.drawRect(200 - 2 * i, 200 - 2 * i, 40, 40)}
```

This is what i want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: You never change the width and height parameters (40,40).

Comment: you need to increase the width and height too (ie the 40s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the width too:

```
for( int i = 20; i <= 26; i++ ) {
    g.drawRect(200 - 2*i, 200 - 2*i, 40 + 4*i, 40 + 4*i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the width and the height

```
g.drawRect(200 - 2 * i, 200 - 2 * i, 40, 40)
//drawRect(x, y, width, height)
//you can see your width and height are constant
```

You can increase it doing something like this:

```
g.drawRect(200 - 2 * i, 200 - 2 * i, 40 + (i + 10), 40 + (i + 10))
```